# c++ universal templated class arithmetic

Tags: c++, templates, operators, typedef, decltype

Let's suppose we are dealing with a class that for some reason has to have some arithmetic operations.

The operations like `tensor_sum` have overloaded operator templates. The problem with this approach seems to be this:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘tensor_sum<T0, T1>::value_type& 

tensor_sum<T0, T1>::operator()(unsigned int) const [with T0 = tensor<int>; T1 = tensor<int>; tensor_sum<T0, T1>::value_type = int; typename T0::value_type = int; typename T1::value_type = int]’:
main.cpp:46:20:   required from here
main.cpp:11:63: error: no match for call to ‘(const tensor<int>) (unsigned int&)’
   value_type & operator () (unsigned int i) const { return t0_(i) + t1_(i); }
                                                            ~~~^~~
main.cpp:32:7: note: candidate: T& tensor<T>::operator()(unsigned int) [with T = int] <near match>
   T & operator () (unsigned int i) { return values_[i]; }
       ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:32:7: note:   passing ‘const tensor<int>*’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
main.cpp:11:72: error: no match for call to ‘(const tensor<int>) (unsigned int&)’
   value_type & operator () (unsigned int i) const { return t0_(i) + t1_(i); }
                                                                     ~~~^~~
main.cpp:32:7: note: candidate: T& tensor<T>::operator()(unsigned int) [with T = int] <near match>
   T & operator () (unsigned int i) { return values_[i]; }
       ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:32:7: note:   passing ‘const tensor<int>*’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
```

For some reason, I can't access the value. But I have overloaded the `() operator`

Anyway here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T0, typename T1>
struct tensor_sum {
  typedef decltype(typename T0::value_type() + typename T1::value_type()) value_type;

  public:
  tensor_sum(const T0 &t0, const T1 &t1) : t0_(t0), t1_(t1) {}

  value_type & operator () (unsigned int i) const { return t0_(i) + t1_(i); }

  private:
  const T0 &t0_;
  const T1 &t1_;
};

template<typename T0, typename T1>
tensor_sum<T0, T1> operator + (const T0 &t0, const T1 &t1) { return tensor_sum<T0, T1>(t0, t1); }

template<typename T0, typename T1>
tensor_sum<T0, T1> operator + (const T0 &t0, const T1 &t1);

template<typename T>
struct tensor {
  typedef T value_type;

  public:
  tensor(const unsigned int s = 0) : size_(s), values_(std::vector<T>(s)) {}
  tensor(const tensor<T> &t) : size_(t.size_), values_(std::vector<T>(t.values_)) {}

  T & operator () (unsigned int i) { return values_[i]; }
  tensor<T> & operator = (const tensor<T> &t) { return tensor<T>(t); }

  private:
  const unsigned int size_;
  std::vector<T> values_;
};

int main() {
  tensor<int> t0(10);
  tensor<int> t1(10);

  tensor_sum<tensor<int>, tensor<int>> ts = t0 + t1;

  std::cout << ts(2) << std::endl; //Can't access value.. why?

  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4wIT9DyGK4GPZwyn)</kbd>

Comment: btw. this `operator +` may be called on any single 2 types (including e.g. `int`).

Comment: In addition to what has already been said, you wanna be careful with this: *"I would reuse those operations over and over again, so I thought it would be simpler to store them all in a separate namespace."* "Storing" them in a separate namespace means that they will not be found by [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), which is kinda important for overloaded operators to work properly…

Comment: There are several other issues with your sample: `tensor_sum` cannot be constructed, `tensor<int>` doesn't have `value_type`, so cannot be used as type of `tensor_sum`, `operator =` return by copy :/ would crash if size mismatch, ...

Comment: Yes operator = would crash if types differ, so I would just create a template for the equal operator.
The main problem is value_type. How can i declare value_type in the tensor struct?

Comment: with appropriate usage of `auto`/`decltype`, you probably don't need `value_type`. But for `tensor`, it would be `T`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tensor_sum<T0, T1> operator + (const T0 &t0, const T1 &t1);
```

return a tensor_sum and tensor has not a operator= with tensor_sum.

so you code means t0 + t1 return a tensor_sum and try to assign to a tensor, and fail of course.

Comment: okay.. i was a bit wrong. I dont have to store the tensor at all... i can just use the tensor_sum struct and from this struct i can overload another operator.
I'll change the code. Hopefully u have another idea why i cant access the tensor_sum with the () operator.